# Dlib on painted face

Tags: opencv, dlib

Will Dlib facial landmark predictor work with unreal faces like this one, if I manually set rectangle with the face? [image]

Comment: Yes it may work in some cases, But I cannot precisely give the accuracy. The is trained with hog features are independent illumination variations of face tone variations, if the input image has enough hog features matching with human face, it would give the desired 72 facial feature points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Dlib predictors were trained on the [HELEN dataset](http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~vuongle2/helen/).

This means the Dlib predictors are very good at detecting anything that looks largely similar to those pictures. It has been trained on a wide variety of human faces using photographs, i.e. actual images of humans.

Whether or not it will detect paintings of humans depends on a numebr of factors such as:

- How closely the "Global Illumination" Matches the training set, I imagine a painted image won't be very close.
- Whether the skin tones match (in greyscale)
- Whether the features are in the right place, right size, right scale etc. (i.e. not a picasso)

I have had success using these predictors on stitched together faces, using camera images, however as with all computer vision questions it's likely a "Try and see" experiment.

You can always train your own predictors with a set of paintings:
 http://dlib.net/train_shape_predictor_ex.cpp.html